# How to communicate between 2 DSP in TI6488

Tags: ti-dsp

hey i am new to DSP. i have given a task to communicate between 2 DSP i.e. inter DSP communication.. for TI6488. i have some examples codes for loop back. but for non loopback how to proceed i have no idea...i am using CCstudio.. please help

Answer (score 1):

You may know which interface you are using between the two dsp first, then I think you must study the manual book of ti6488, through it you can know the using method of the port. If you want to get the detail, you may offer some code and block diagram.

Comment: hey, I am using the Antenna Interface for communication between the DSP. I am going through the loopback code available with the Board. Now i want to try for non loop back for communicating between 2 dsp's.Can u suggest me how to proceed.